# Why I can not connect to MySql .Net with Driver connection String as it works with Delphi's TADOQuery?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database-connection, ado

I have Connection string like this:

```
Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=data; UID=root; Password=admin;
```

My program written in Delphi connects right. But the same Connection string doesn't work in C# .net standard System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection object.

the error is:

```
System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'driver'. at
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString, SqlCredential credential)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
```

Comment: Because .Net is not Delphi. For connection strings see: https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Comment: You need to use `OdbcConnection` not `SqlConnection` with that connection string. But if you're connecting to MySQL from .NET, I'd strongly recommend _not_ using the ODBC driver and using https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/ instead; it's much more modern.